# How to Update a List of entities properly?

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to update a List of entities, using EF4.

1. I have a ViewModel Object (retrieved from a web form) passed to my method named "**productToUpdate**" that contains a List "Labels".
2. I get the corresponding list of objects from the database with a Linq Query to an anonymous object named "**requeteValsLabels**"
   I did this manually (testing the id's in the foreach loop) as follow, but I imagine this is not the best way to do it?

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < productToUpdate.Labels.Count; i++)
           {
               foreach (var item in productToUpdate.Labels)
               {
                   if (requeteValsLabels[i].ID == item.IdValeurLabel){
                   requeteValsLabels[i].Valeur = item.Valeur;
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to use the following pattern

```
        foreach (var item in productToUpdate.Labels) {
            Entity e = new Entity { Id = item.IdValeurLabel};
            context.EntitySet.Attach(e);
            e.Valeur = item.Valeur;
        }
```

this prevent a loading (select) trip to the database but:

- as no load occur, you can't be sure that the ID exists in the DB, so you may have <del>an insert</del> an exception for trying to update a non existing row.
- as no load occur, you can't check for a label modification and may update with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more efficient way is to join the collections and then copy the values:

```
var query = from item in productToUpdate.Labels
            join label in requeteValsLabels on item.IdValeurLabel equals label.ID
            select new { item, label };

foreach (var pair in query.ToList())
{
    pair.label.Valuer = pair.item.Valuer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your outer loop correct?  Should it be

```
for (int i = 0; i < requeteValsLabels.Count; i++)
```

Are you looking for a more compact way to write this?  Try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < requeteValsLabels.Count; i++)
{
    requeteValsLabels[i].Valeur = productToUpdate.Labels
        .First(x => x.IdValeurLabel == requeteValsLabels[i].ID).Valeur;
}
```

Careful though.. First() will throw an exception if there isn't a element that satisfies the condition.